# Which episode of "Battle of the Planets" showed all the team's vehicles docking with the Phoenix?

Tags: episode-identification, battle-of-the-planets, gatchaman

In one episode of [Battle of the Planets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_the_Planets), all of the four smaller vehicles ([G-1](http://gatchaman.wikia.com/wiki/G-1), [G-2](http://gatchaman.wikia.com/wiki/G-2), [G-3](http://gatchaman.wikia.com/wiki/G-3) and [G-4](http://gatchaman.wikia.com/wiki/G-4)) are seen docking with the [Phoenix](http://gatchaman.wikia.com/wiki/God_Phoenix). Which episode was that?

I remember that some (all?) of the vehicles were shown in their form before they transmutate, eg G-1 is shown as a prop plane and G-2 as a stock car racer.

If no one knows the BofP episode, the relevant Gatchaman episode is also OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trawling through many YouTube episodes, I found it. It is [episode 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Battle_of_the_Planets_episodes): [Beast with a Sweet Tooth](https://youtu.be/BrhGboio1E8). See this link from 5 minutes 27 seconds:

I may have not correctly remembered the pre-transmutate part of the question. One episode with the pre-transmutate G-1 is [Ghost Ship of the Planet Mir](http://youtu.be/LlHACr3eLpA) and for G-2 it is [The Awesome Ray Force](http://youtu.be/84mAyxQv8zE).